# retrieving document that redirects with a javascript using jsoup

Tags: javascript, redirect, jsoup

i'm trying to make a crawler using jsoup.
the link i have parsed has the pattern:

> "baseurl/map/getmap.cfm?code=1234"

**when trying to enter the link above using the browser**, the link is redirected to something like

> "baseurl/maps/getmap.cfm?id=53545&transid=456"

and i get the document that i want (via view page source of the browser)

**but when using jsoup** to retrieve it,

> Jsoup.connect("baseurl/maps/getmap.cfm?code=1234").get();

it gives me this html document:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    location.href ="baseUrl/maps/getmap.cfm?id=4552454&transid=1392335422404";
</script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

**so what i do is** extract the link of the above document and use it to retrieve the document,
**however** it is giving me a **blank html**. 
also, when i use

> baserul/maps/getmap?id=53545&transid=456

directly in the browser i am getting the correct .

**i also tried**

> Jsoup.connect(link).followRedirects(true).get()

but it is not working

**How can i work around with this?**

EDIT:
added missing "=" sign in urls

i can now retrieve the html using

> "baseurl/maps/getmap.cfm?id=53545&transid=456"

from the browser, but still cannot retrieve it using jsoup

**UPDATE**

Exception report is giving Status=500

Comment: Use some debugger (like Fiddler) to find the params the browser is sending to the server. Maybe you're missing a cookie with session ID or something else.

Comment: I had the same problem. One walk around is to move to your baseurl's api.